# Custom Page counters do not work in Print Preview (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-counter

I am working on AngularJS project where I need to print a table with unknown rows (usually over 200, all rows automatically generated using ng-repeat). However, I need to count the total page numbers and show them in the table header in the upper right corner in the following format: "Page X of Y".

I have read many articles related with paging, CSS counters (counter-reset, counter-increment etc.) They all work in a way, that they detect the element which repeats on every page. In my case, every row has the same class and there is no unique identifier which helps me to count the pages and increment the current page counter.

The current HTML that I have is similar to this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td> <-- Page X of Y --> </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <!-- N rows here -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Edit1:**

The preview needs to be custom with disabled default header and footer, even though they already include paging

Comment: Do you mean you have too many data to show at one time and you need to divide them into Y pages?

Comment: No. Let's say that the data is displayed on 5 pages. Now, when I print the document, I need to display the total number of pages on the print preview screen (Chrome). The problem is that I need to disable the default header and footer, and instead of that, display the total number of pages in the generated table header.